# What is sequence number and why is it used as the ACK number for the next ACK packet?

Tags: wireshark, tcp, handshake

I am currently trying to learn the TCP session creating (3 way handshake) process in detail. I was wondering what the sequence number means and also why is the ack num for the next ACK packet always the sequence number of the previous packet + 1?

Sorry if this made no sense. I have attached images to help visualize my question.

[image: [SYN ACK Packet Sequence Number]]

[image: [ACK Packet ACK Num is Sequence Number of SYN ACK Packet + 1]]

Comment: This isn't a security question, but a networking basics question. And this is all really easy to look up: https://www.google.com/search?q=tcp+sequence+number